# Curvature of a beam when subjected to an axial force

Tags: stress-strain, structural-beam

How do you calculate the curvature of a beam due to any forces acting parallel to the beam? Intuitively, a beam in real life would bend perpendicular to the force to form an arc. How is this calculated? From my understanding, Euler-Bernoulli Beam theory cannot be used?

For example, how do you solve for the equation of the massless beam in the diagram below, where the walls squash the inner beam to curve? 
[image: Massless beam]

Comment: try posting this on the engineering stack exchange.

Comment: Is it Euler buckling: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_engineering_theory#Buckling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve it as a slender column in compression, for which closed-form solutions are available. The failure mode is buckling (or outward bowing). Interestingly,  and the critical load for the onset of buckling depends on the stiffness of the beam and not its yield strength. This is because the buckling onset is defined as that point where the compressive load places the column into a state where a vanishingly small lateral perturbation will grow without bound and cause the column to suddenly bow outwards, and collapse in bending. Per Rob's comment, this is called Euler buckling.

From wikipedia (sorry, I do not know how to repair the formatting):

When subjected to compressive forces it is possible for structural elements to deform significantly due to the destabilising effect of that load. The effect can be initiated or exacerbated by possible inaccuracies in manufacture or construction.

The [Euler buckling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_engineering_theory#Buckling) formula defines the axial compression force which will cause a strut (or column) to fail in buckling.

$$F=\frac {\pi ^{2}EI}{(Kl)^{2}}$$

where

- $F$ = maximum or critical force (vertical load on column)
- $E$ = modulus of elasticity,
- $I$ = area moment of inertia, or second moment of area
- $l$ = unsupported length of column,
- $K$ = column effective length factor, whose value depends on the conditions of end support of the column, as follows.
- For both ends pinned (hinged, free to rotate), $K = 1.0$.
- For both ends fixed, $K = 0.50$.
- For one end fixed and the other end pinned, $K\approx  0.70$.
- For one end fixed and the other end free to move laterally, $K = 2.0$.

In the design of ultraminiature point probes for electrically testing extremely small circuitry, it is common to use gold-plated wires of fine gauge as probes. they are susceptible to buckling and for this reason are sometimes made of gold-plated tungsten wire instead of copper or (solid) gold, because Young's modulus for tungsten is a bit higher than that of the other metals. This furnishes greater stiffness for a given wire diameter and hence a more buckling-resistant probe.

Comment: wouldn't it far, far, far better to actually explain you answer?

Comment: I believe in brevity... the OP can google "slender column in compression" and obtain a far more thorough exposition of this topic than I could provide here: basically, it's a solved problem, and if you know what it's called, then it requires almost no effort to find the details.

Comment: and this is not the first time I have answered a question this way on the stack exchange. A lot of the time, all it takes to move forward is to know 1) what the problem is called in the specific community that deals with it, and 2) that it is a solved problem.

Comment: But you missed the tiny issue of  this being an answer that is pretty much [your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: OK, see my edit. is that better?

Comment: considerably.  Personally I would actually add an example with the equations and their solution+solution derivation, but that's just me.

Comment: see second edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72432/discussion-between-itamarg3-and-niels-nielsen).